# Sending data top IoT Central from Node-Red, not requiring dps-keygen

Tags: node-red, azure-iot-central

I am using Node-Red to acquire MQTT data from a SCADA system. The data is ingested by subscribing to topics on an external MQTT broker, it contains both telemetry and error/events from specific assets.

I would like to use the rules configuration engine in IoT Central to setup triggers for telemetry and event data. One obvious drawback with IoT Central as it is right now, is that every single event has to be added manually which is tedious for assets with 300+ events.

In Node-Red I do a fair amount of data transformation of the incoming data before sending it to onwards. I have nor problem of sending it to a "normal" IoT Hub in my Azure subscription.

When reading up on oT Central I did find a way to use three specific fields for a created real device, using dps-keygen on Windows, to create an extended connection string that works in the Azure IoT Hub node in Node-Red.

Using it, data is actually received in IoT Central.

The problem is though that I need to send data from 100´s of assets into IoT Central. It seems like the only way to send data into IoT Central from Node-Red is to tediously create the connection string for every device using dps-keygen and then manually add that very string to the node in Node-Red. Not having the incoming connection string settable programmatically in Node-Red (i.e. using a function node) is hugely problematic.

Is there any way to make onboarding of devices added to IoT Central easier
to use from within Node-Red? There is an Export Devices option that export SAS keys for NodeJS clients. can´t that be used in Node-Red directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably directly re-use [the code](https://github.com/Azure/dps-keygen/blob/master/dps.js) for creating a connection string from a device key and scope ID. You can surely export your list of devices from IoT Central as a CSV file and process this file in your Node-RED flow so a to turn each row and associated device ID/device key/scope ID into connection strings?

Answer (score 0):

You should utilize programatically functionality of [Azure IotHub Device Provisioning Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-dps/about-iot-dps).

See node.js  example of how to issue calls and read connection information - https://github.com/Azure/iotc-device-bridge.